# Selenium C# - click element, wait until page refreshes and check the element again

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have an element on website that changes its text when it is clicked. However, when the element is clicked, webpage refreshes and only after it refreshes the element text changes. I made a POM method in Selenium WebDriver C# that tests this functionality:

```
public void ChangeLanguage(string language)
    {
        //Get current language and then change it
        this.executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", currentLanguage);
        //Wait until page reloads and language change button is visible again
        wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("language-change-link")));
    }

[Test]
        public void ChangeLanguage()
        {
            ExtentTest test = null;
            LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(_driver);
            ICapabilities driverCapabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver)_driver).Capabilities;
            string currentLanguage = null;

            try
            {
                //Create test
                test = extent.CreateTest("Change language").Info("Test started")
                    .Info("Browser:  " + (driverCapabilities.HasCapability("browserName") ? driverCapabilities.GetCapability("browserName") : "unknown") +
                    (driverCapabilities.HasCapability("version") ? " / " + driverCapabilities.GetCapability("version") : ""));

                //Get current language
                currentLanguage = loginPage.currentLanguage.Text;
                test.Log(Status.Info, "Currently selected language: " + currentLanguage);

                //Get current language and then change it
                loginPage.ChangeLanguage(currentLanguage);
                test.Log(Status.Info, "Switching languages...");

                switch (currentLanguage)
                {
                    //Current language is english
                    case "English":
                        try
                        {
                            Assert.AreEqual(loginPage.currentLanguage.Text, "German");
                            test.Log(Status.Pass, "Previously selected language: " + currentLanguage + ". New language: " + loginPage.currentLanguage.Text + ".");
                        }
                        catch (AssertionException)
                        {
                            test.Log(Status.Fail, "Language was not set! Expected language: German");
                            test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(Reports.CaptureScreenshot(_driver, "CloudKiosk", "testScreenshot_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks));
                        }
                        break;
                    //Current language is german
                    case "German":
                        try
                        {
                            Assert.AreEqual(loginPage.currentLanguage.Text, "English");
                            test.Log(Status.Pass, "Previously selected language: " + currentLanguage + ". New language: " + loginPage.currentLanguage.Text + ".");
                        }
                        catch (AssertionException)
                        {
                            test.Log(Status.Fail, "Language was not set! Expected language: English");
                            test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(Reports.CaptureScreenshot(_driver, "CloudKiosk", "testScreenshot_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                test.Log(Status.Fail, "Test execution failed: " + e.Message + " ---> " + e.Message).CreateNode("Error details").Log(Status.Error, e.ToString());
                test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(Reports.CaptureScreenshot(_driver, "CloudKiosk", "testScreenshot_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks));
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that once the element is clicked the webpage refreshes but the code immediately checks the element text before the page even refreshes, thus giving me a negative test result. Is there a way to to make the test wait for the webpage to refresh after clicking the element before checking its text?

Comment: The best way to do this is to wait for the current element to become stale. There is an ExpectedCondition for this. Once the element becomes stale, you know that the page has reloaded. Now you wait for the element to be visible/clickable (whatever you need) and then continue your test.

Answer (score 0):

If you have loader on the page then you can wait for the load to disappear first then check for the text else you can wait for the element with old text to disappear and then wait for the element with new text. Here is some code which you can use for element to get disappear:

```
 var defaultWait = new WebDriverWait(this, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
 defaultWait.Until(
                    ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath((selector)))
                    );
```

Comment: There is no loader after clicking on the element, the page just refreshes.

Comment: Ok then you can look for the element with the new text to appear I think that will resolve your problem.

Comment: thanks, I changed the code up to check if the text changed!